# What is the expected behavior and purpose of model.trainable=False in tensorflow keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, tf.keras

It seems setting `model.trainable=False` in tensorflow keras does nothing except for to print a wrong model.summary(). Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
IMG_SHAPE = (160, 160, 3)

# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False, 
                                               weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False
# for layer in base_model.layers:
#     layer.trainable=False
bc=[] #before compile
ac=[] #after compile
for layer in base_model.layers:
    bc.append(layer.trainable)
print(np.all(bc)) #True
print(base_model.summary()) ##this changes to show no trainable parameters but that  is wrong given the output to previous np.all(bc)
base_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
for layer in base_model.layers:
    ac.append(layer.trainable)
print(np.all(ac)) #True
print(base_model.summary()) #this changes to show no trainable parameters but that  is wrong given the output to previous np.all(ac)
```

In light of this - What is the expected behavior and purpose of model.trainable=False in tensorflow keras?

Comment: What's the question here exactly?

Comment: of course!! please see the edit and thank you for pointing out

Comment: Something seems entirely wrong. I think that you should submit an issue.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29535

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29535

I think this issue could help.

If you are looking for a way to not update some weights in your model I would suggest using the parameter `var_list` in the `minimize` function from your `Optimizer`.

For some reason when creating a model from keras Tensorflow switch all tf.Variables to True, and since all are Tensors we are not able to update the value to False.

What I do in my code is create scope names for all pretrained models and loop over it adding all layers that are not from my pretrained model.

```
trainable_variables = []
variables_collection = tf.get_collection('learnable_variables')
for layer in tf.trainable_variables():
    if 'vgg_model' not in layer.name:
        trainable_variables.append(layer)
        tf.add_to_collection('learnable_variables', layer)

grad = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
train_step = grad.minimize(tf.reduce_sum([loss]), var_list=trainable_variables)
```

Watch out for global_initializer as well, since it will overwrite your pretrained Weights as well. You can solve that by using `tf.variables_initializer` and passing a list of variables you want to add weights.

```
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(variables_collection))
```

Source I used when trying to solve this problem 
[Is it possible to make a trainable variable not trainable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326002/is-it-possible-to-make-a-trainable-variable-not-trainable)

[TensorFlow: Using tf.global_variables_initializer() after partially loading pre-trained weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744944/tensorflow-using-tf-global-variables-initializer-after-partially-loading-pre)